# getElementById($string) returns NULL

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm new to php and I'm a little confused by this error when I try to access a DOMElement from the file I'm working in:

`'Creating default object from empty value in [path]'`

where path is the destination of the php file causing the error. I've tried validating the form before calling $dom->getElementById($string), but this just causes other errors like

`'No declaration for element span in [path]'`

newEmptyPHP.php contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <span id="mySpan">Hello, World!</span>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load('newEmptyPHP.php');
    $dom->validate();

    $label = $dom->getElementById('mySpan');
    $label->nodeValue = "Hello, pluto!";
?>
```

To clarify: I understand that `$dom->getElementById($id)` is returning null and thus I can't access the span element I'm trying to change. I have worked with ASP.NET and JavaScript before and I am familiar with `document.getElementById` in JavaScript, so I may be misunderstanding how things are done in PHP as opposed to JavaScript; I just need to know what I'm doing wrongly that's causing `getElementById()` to return null. I couldn't find anything that helped in other questions, so let me know if you have any insight to share. Thank you!

Comment: What is the contents of `newEmptyPHP.php`?

Comment: What is the content of newEmptyPHP.php?

Comment: I should have clarified; newEmptyPHP is the same file all this stuff is contained in; could that be the problem, that I'm trying to access something that hasn't been initialized yet? (added edits for clarification)

Comment: You cannot use PHP as you would use Javascript. So, put the HTML in a seperate file, and use the saveHTML() DOMDocument method to output your changed HTML. http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

Comment: you should also use the `loadHTMLFile()` method for loading HTML and not `load()` which loads XML: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, validating HTML5 with DOMDocument doesn't work very well; this is probably related to libxml.

Secondly, loading the same file your script is in won't work as expected unless you either separate the HTML into its own file and use `->loadHTMLFile()` or use output buffering:

```
<?php

ob_start();

?>
<html><body><span id="mySpan">Hello, world!</span></body></html>
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(ob_get_clean());
// ...
```